# How do you make a Word add in create a table that can be editted at a later time?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, openxml, office-interop

I am trying to make a Microsoft Word add in that generates a table at the currently selected location and do so in such a way that it can be referenced and editted at a latter time.  So far I have been wording with office.interop.  My experimental code so far is as such:

```
Public Sub onTestButton1(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    Dim oWord As Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim currentDocument As Word.Document = oWord.ActiveDocument
    Dim oTable As Word.Table

    Dim extentedDocument As Document = currentDocument.GetVstoObject()
    richTextControl1 = extentedDocument.Controls.AddRichTextContentControl("richTextControl1")
    richTextControl1.Title = "testTable"

    oTable = currentDocument.Tables.Add(richTextControl1.Range, 2, 2)
End Sub
```

The result of this code is a content control wrapped table and all is well except it inserts a line break above and below the table inside the content control.  How can I achieve this without these line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the table first, then use its Range to insert the Control.